# conectar a vários sites com cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Se houvesse uma lista com 10 sites, ou mais, usando cURL para me conectar e puchar um conteúdo de cada site, qual seria a forma mais efetiva, que daria menos tempo entre uma conexão e outra..
Ou seja, qual a boa prática para este caso, algo como:

Iniciar o cURL -> setar opções-> fechar, e iniciar denovo para o próximo site,.. 
obs: as opções, como são as mesmas para todos os sites que vou conectar, posso criar um array e usar o `curl_setopt_array`, para não ficar um código gigante.

abrindo e fechando conexão para cada site, considerando que as opções do cURL seriam as mesmas, a única diferente seria a `curlopt_url`..?

Answer (score 1):

Em momentos assim que eu sinto falta de threads em PHP... :(

Considerando que apenas a URL será alterada a cada requisição, você pode usar a seguinte lógica:

```
$ch = curl_init();

// todos os curl_setopt aqui, exceto a URL

foreach ( $urls as $url )
{
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_exec( $ch );
}

curl_close( $ch );
```

Mais sobre cURL aqui: http://rberaldo.com.br/trabalhando-com-a-biblioteca-curl/